# How can I create XAdES-T signature for binary content with xades4j?

Tags: java, xades4j

I want to create detached XAdES-T signature for binary files. I've found in an other stack overflow post the xades4j tool. But I've found only examples for creating signature for xml documents. How can I sign binary file with xades4j?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have different options to setup the signed data objects depending on you scenario. Check out the `xades4j` wiki on GitHub:

- https://github.com/luisgoncalves/xades4j/wiki/DefiningSignedResources
- https://github.com/luisgoncalves/xades4j/wiki/SignatureTypes#detached-signatures-over-non-xml-resources

Also, Apache XML Security (the foundation for `xades4j`) [supports `file:` URIs](http://santuario.apache.org/javafaq.html), so you might also use this along with [specifying the base URI](http://luisgoncalves.github.io/xades4j/javadocs/1.3.1/reference/xades4j/production/SignedDataObjects.html#withBaseUri(java.lang.String)).